# Order of zero of $f(z)=\frac{d^{50}}{{dz}^{50}}[z^{100}\sin(z^{10})]$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> What is the order of $z=0$ of the function $f(z)=\frac{d^{50}}{{dz}^{50}}[z^{100}\sin(z^{10})]$?

Answer (score 1):

Write $\sin (z^{10})=z^{10}-\dfrac{z^{30}}{3}+\dfrac{z^{50}}{5}-\ldots $

$=z^{10}(1-\dfrac{z^{3}}{3}+\dfrac{z^{5}}{5}-\ldots )$

If $f(z)=z^{100}\sin {z^{10}}=z^{110}(1-\dfrac{z^{3}}{3}+\dfrac{z^{5}}{5}-\ldots )$.

$f^{'}(z)=110z^{109}(1-\dfrac{z^{3}}{3}+\dfrac{z^{5}}{5}-\ldots )\times z^{100}(-z^2+z^4-\ldots )$.

$=z^{109}\{110(1-\dfrac{z^{3}}{3}+\dfrac{z^{5}}{5}-\ldots )+z^3(-1+z^2+\dots ).\}$

Note that the term in the bracket is never $0$ as there is $1$ in the expression.

Hence On differentiating $f(z)$ $50 $ times the power of $z$ in $f(z)$ becomes $60$ .(How?)

> Just notice on differentiating once power of $z$ becomes $109$ ,on differentiating twice power of $z$ becomes $108$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f$ is holomorphic. We can expand its Taylor series about $0$:

$$ f(z) = z^{100} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} z^{20j + 10}
$$
Setting $j$ to $0$ gives the order:
$$ z^{100} \frac{(-1)^0}{(2\cdot 0 + 1)!} z^{20 \cdot 0 +10} = \frac{(-1)^0}{(2\cdot 0 + 1)!} z^{110}
$$
Now subtract this order by $50$...

Comment: I am not certain what you are accomplishing after you find the power series for $f$? Please explain what theorem or result you are using.

Comment: @Analysis15 If $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $0$, the first $m-1$ terms of $f$'s series expansion centred at $0$ vanishes.

Comment: Yes, but how does setting $j=0$ yield the order? What is $a$? Why subtract by 50? I'm lost...

Comment: @Analysis15 Setting $j=0$ gives the first non-zero term of the power series. $a$ is a placeholder for the constant. Subtraction by $50$ corresponds to the $50$-order differentiation.

Comment: Why do we need a placeholder and I am still lost on what you are doing...

Comment: @Analysis15 I have modified the answer. I think it is more clear now.

Comment: But, the first term doesn't even vanish and the coefficient on the first term is non-zero, so I don't see were I would go from there.

Comment: @Analysis15 This power series is not written in standard form. That is, the index of the power series $j$ does not correspond to the power of $z$.